# Laravel {!! Form::open() !!} doesn't work within AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, laravel

I'm using `Laravel 5.0 + AngularJS` to build some website. The problem is when I use laravel illuminate, things like

```
{!! Form::open() !!}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

are not compiled into forms, instead, the plain texts are displayed.

I guess it's because I'm also using angular, which already have certain use of '**`{}`**';

when I use **`{!! Form::open() !!}`** in another page with no angular it works normally.

How can I use laravel form inside angular app? (need the features like csrf token)

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with angularjs. AngularJs does not use {!! !!}} And if you are doing the right thing Laravel compiles these into html before returning to view

Comment: But when I include {!! Form::open() !!}{!! Form::close() !!} in another page in the project it worked normally (that page doesn't have any angular usage)

Comment: Let me see the complete blade template and how you return the view from your controller

Comment: Now it's just a single page view, the template is at: https://bitbucket.org/xuan9230/fpv-freerider/src/195ea91789f8c2899a956baf37610cd2befa475f/fpv-freerider/resources/views/landing/landing-index.php?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default line275,276

Comment: Never mind.. I was so stupid to name it as index.blade.php instead of index.php.. Also thanks for @Sean Perkins, you introduced an excellent method which I can use in the future!

Comment: You don't need to use @sean tags unless when very necessary.. To tell blade not to compile a tag simple do this `@{{ variable }}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will either need to change the blade syntax for laravel or change it for AngularJS. I tend to lean on changing it for Lavavel.

```
Blade::setContentTags('<%', '%>');        // for variables and all things Blade
Blade::setEscapedContentTags('<%%', '%%>');   // for escaped data
```

Add that into a common file, such as `routes.php`.

Update your references from `{!!` to `<%` and `!!}` to `%>`.

Edit:

If you would instead like to do this on the AngularJS side, you can with adding this into your `app.js` file (credits: scotch.io).

```
var sampleApp = angular.module('sampleApp', [], function($interpolateProvider) {
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('<%');
    $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('%>');
});
```

Replace the module name with your project's app module name.

Comment: Tried to change on the Laravel side, adding them into routes.php but didn't really work for me.. still showing 
<% Form::open() %> <% Form::close() %>